# Is Piston ready for OAuth?

Tags: django, oauth, django-piston

I tried using [Piston](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/overview/) for a simple API, hoping to use its OAuth support.  But the first time I hit the endpoint after enabling OAuth, I got an error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist: oauth/challenge.html
```

and sure enough, there is no such file.

Does OAuth work in Piston?  Am I making a stupid mistake?

Comment: How's that coming along?

Comment: @Ned - think you just accepted my answer - did you ever confirm it being a bug in Piston?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope - that looks like a bug in Piston. `oauth/challenge.html` is referenced [here](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/src/6b0364d98837/piston/authentication.py#cl-256), but does not exist anywhere in that project (see Piston's [templates folder](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/src/tip/piston/templates/)).

Could you try creating an empty `oauth/challenge.html` file somewhere in one of your directories specified in [`TEMPLATE_DIRS`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-dirs) setting?

Comment: It's not really a bug. For reusable apps, you're supposed to write your own templates.

Comment: @oliland - for some things yeah, but surely not for issuing an oauth challenge?

Answer (score 0):

The challenge method in the authentication object is called when checking is_authenticated fails. I haven't tested this, but I am led to believe that challenge.html is most likely rendered when authorization has failed and an error needs to be displayed.

This is only a guess, but I think that it makes sense.