# Any good tutorials on using OAuth with Piston?

Tags: django, oauth, django-piston

I've looked at the [relevant section of the Piston documentation](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/wiki/Documentation#oauth), but it only seems to focus on how to turn it on, not what it would look like for clients or how to test it to verify it's working. The [example](http://bitbucket.org/jespern/django-piston/src/tip/examples/blogserver/README.txt) only seems to use HTTP Basic and `curl`. Finally, [Ned Batchelder's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732277/is-piston-ready-for-oauth) makes it look like a tutorial is in order. Thanks.

Comment: I'll write one if I figure it out.  Back to searching.

Comment: I am also interested in this.  I will return if I make any progress.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've just found one tutorial at http://blog.carduner.net/2010/01/26/django-piston-and-oauth/. Hope this would help someone.

Comment: The timing on this answer couldn't have been any better. Thank you!

Comment: The tutorial only deals with how to set up Piston in your Django app. The question specifically asked how it would work for a client, and how to test it in a better way than curl (for example, in your Django unit tests). I'm looking for precisely that, and this answer doesn't cover it at all.

Answer (score 1):

I did benjamin dell; at what point are you? The endless loop? In that case; add this function to yourapp.api.views:

```
# Create your views here.
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def request_token_ready(request, token):
    error = request.GET.get('error', '')
    ctx = RequestContext(request, {
        'error' : error,
        'token' : token
    })
    return render_to_response(
        'piston/request_token_ready.html',
        context_instance = ctx
    )
```

and set settings.OAUTH_CALLBACK_VIEW = "api.views.request_token_ready"

Comment: this is used when the consumer doesn't provide a callback_url, correct?